# Inconsistent styling in a one-off setting?

Tags: html, css

I've been working on [this website](https://www.salsalabs.com/) that has two CTA/Buttons on the page. The one in the header is Orange and the one in the hero is white-outlined.

My problem is that I, my staff, and everyone else sees it as it's supposed to:
[image: Correct Styling]

However, this one guy from an agency we work with has a one-off situation where he sees it as this:
[image: Incorrect Styling]

He is using Google Chrome V47 (same as me) on a Mac OSx machine (same as me)

---

Here is the CSS I am using for the buttons:

**Orange-Button**

```
.button, button, input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], input[type="button"] {
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #F3901D;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**White Button**

```
.home-sp-footer-cta-3 {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: none;
    border: solid 4px white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}
```

What could be causing this one-off situation? Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's a massive difference. Are you sure he is not viewing a cached version prior to those button styles?

Comment: Has he tried opening it in incognito mode? Does he still see the same thing?

Comment: This is a matter of cached version view, just ask to the "client" to clean the cache of the browser. It happens a lot

Comment: Try having him hit Cmd+Shift+N and then navigating to the URL (or hitting Cmd+F5 on the page). It looks like a cached issue.

Comment: I just gave him a call to check if he's cached. He's an agency so i would *assume* they'd know to check that but I may be wrong.

Comment: No answer, awaiting a call back :/

Comment: "[...] so i would assume they'd know to check that" - never assume this, people will let you down... To be sure, make them press F12 (opens inspector), then right click on the refresh button (next to location bar) and click *Empty Cache and Hard Reload*.

Comment: Alright, just an update. He reset his cache and cookies, nothing. His JS is enabled. On Incognito AND any other browser it appears fine. It's only on normal Google Chrome where it occurs. Also i noticed that when his loads the `<button>...</button>` html is replaced with an <img>. Maybe it's a problem with the COS we are using, or perhaps an extension is blocking it on his end?

Comment: If he's getting the img tags it means something is making the site think his browser can't into button tags. Call it up in IE and set compatibility to 8 or earlier, then dom explore, you'll see what I mean. You should probably also do something about the javascript errors and hilariously bad load time of your page, but that's another problem entirely.... Probably.

Comment: @abluejelly I figured something is breaking it. I just got pulled onto this staff after they ousted the rest of them. So it's a whole new site to me. Yea, the errors and load time are ridiculous, but we need the site to work til December where I and my team will begin a complete overhaul. Will look through the DOM in IE, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Ether heh I know that, I'm the first full-time in my position for 10 years, so I've got a lot of.... Fun in my job too haha. The IE thing was just to demonstrate it, since modern IE's dev tools let you time travel without having to keep a copy of ancient firefox with the last Firebug that worked on it for HTML5 shim testing. Might wanna check on whatever HTML5 shim you guys are using, his browser is probably lying about however that shim tests if it's needed.

Comment: II'll have to dive into it. Like I said, it's only and I mean only on regular chrome. If he pulls it in Incognito it's perfect.

Comment: If it's not a cache problem, then it's probably an add-on messing with the page (they're disabled in incognito mode). Tell them to navigate to `about:extensions` and disable one after another, repeatedly testing again.